# Android source master version build time

Tags: android, time, compilation

I followed the [Building the Sytem guide](https://source.android.com/source/building-running.html) in order to run the source I have already downloaded.

I have a 2-core CPU 3GHz

I configured `launch aosp_arm-eng` and then ran `make -j4`.

It's been 1.5 hours and it hasn't finished yet; is this a normal waiting time ?

If this is the case will it take that long every time I compile it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is logical don't worry, in fact the first time only it should take a long time(basically when it builds everything).